# Should we prove this?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Terence Tao's Analysis I. I'm at section $2$.

I want to ask, should we prove this: "If $a = b$, then $a++ = b ++$" ?

I have no serious issue with approach of this text but I  couldn't decide this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this notation; what is meant by $a++$?

Comment: a++ is the successor of a as in the Peano axioms. I think Terence Tao probably invented that notation for his book/lectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of statement is so basic that it is usually not proved. You can take it for granted that if $a=b$ you may replace any instance of $a$ anywhere with $b$. So $a++ = b++$ etc.

Another way to look at it: $x \rightarrow x++$ is a function and a function has only one value for any input argument. I think functions only come later in the text. That's a slight problem with Tao's Analysis book. He rigorously introduces the number systems, but he doesn't introduce basic set theory beforehand, which would make those things easier.